# Экспортирование функции в Typescript. This as any

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, typescript, export, this

Использую Typescript Strict Mode. Необходимо реализовать что-то похожее на это

```
export default function FOO(): any {
    let that = this
    that.foo = function(){
       return {
          view: "form",
          id: "sample",
          borderless: true,
          elements: []
       }
    }
    return {
        id: 'form_data_vehicle_owner',
        view: 'form',
        autoheight: true,
        elements: [
           that.foo, // foo не вызывается || this.foo рискуем потерять контекст
        ]
    }
}
```

Выпадает ошибка TS2683. Как можно изменить код? То что первое нагуглил 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007891/ts2683ts-this-implicitly-has-type-any-because-it-does-not-have-a-type-ann?rq=1

Но я не понимаю как это применить к моему коду.

Comment: ну так собственно у тебя `this` и может быть `any`. В чем смысл экспортировать функцию, внутри которой обращаться к `this` - значение которого может быть любым?

Comment: @Grundy в том то и проблема, мне нужно чтобы this был привязан к экспортируемой функции. Если отталкиваться от моих начальных знаний JS, то функция тоже объект, и мне необходимо, чтобы она имела  внутренние методы. А пример просто сокращенный. Этот this.foo вызывается в других внутренних методах

Comment: @AntonGult, что значит _this был привязан к экспортируемой функции_?

Comment: @Grundy чтобы this содержал контекст exported функции, а не any. я бы объявил через let foo и не парился, но я использую webix внутри exported, который не принимает функции без this.

Comment: @AntonGult, _чтобы this содержал контекст exported функции_ - а это что значит? В любом случае, ты пробовал использовать решение по ссылке? `this.foo = ()=>{}`

Comment: @Grundy да, пробовал, не помогло. Дополнил вопрос. может быть так станет яснее. От overthesanity похоже на окончательный ответ

Comment: @AntonGult, Неа, совсем не стало яснее. Абсолютно непонятно зачем тебе `this`. если ты его уберешь - у тебя все продолжит работать. Если же ты хочешь добавить поле в саму функцию FOO - То так и пиши `FOO.foo`

Comment: @Grundy фреймворк Webix имеет отдельную область видимости, при работе с ним необходимо функцию foo передавать через this. Более того, контекст теряется поэтому предварительно в FOO необходимо let that = this. И уже в конце кода вызывать как that.foo. Поэтому мне необходимо определить this не как any.

Comment: _this.foo рискуем потерять контекст_ - не рискует, по крайней мере в примере - ты внутри foo Не используешь `this`, следовательно тебе все равно с каким `this` будет вызвана эта функция.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в данном случае не в том, что `this` имеет тип `any`, а в том, что это нигде не указано.

Чтобы это указать явно, нужно воспользоваться [`параметром this`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters)

```
export default function FOO(this:any): any {
```